AttributeError: object has no attribute 'method'
I'm making a plugin for blender and I have some data types that contain drawing functions. However, when calling these functions on two specific classes, it throws an AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[REDACTED]/blender/4.2/scripts/addons/manifoldclothing/gen/GenPanel.py", line 17, in draw
    context.active_object.manifoldHuman.maleBody.draw(layout, context)
  File "[REDACTED]/blender/4.2/scripts/addons/manifoldclothing/data/FemaleBodyData.py", line 35, in draw
    self.neck.draw(box, context)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'LongLimbData' object has no attribute 'draw'

LimbData:
import bpy

class LimbData(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    length: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Length")
    
    def draw(self, layout, context):
        layout.prop(self, "length")

LongLimbData:
import bpy
from .LimbData import *

class LongLimbData(LimbData):
    thickness: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Thickness")

    def draw(self, layout, context):
        super().draw(layout, context)
        layout.prop(self, "thickness")


FemaleSpineData:
import bpy
from .LongLimbData import *

class FemaleSpineData(LongLimbData):
    lowerWidth: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Lower Width")
    upperWidth: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Upper Width")
    
    def draw(self, layout, context):
        super().draw(layout, context)
        layout.prop(self, "lowerWidth")
        layout.prop(self, "upperWidth")

FemaleBodyData:
import bpy
from .BodyData import *
from .FemaleChestData import *
from .FemaleHipData import *
from .FemaleThighData import *

class FemaleBodyData(BodyData):
    hips: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=FemaleHipData)
    spine: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=FemaleSpineData)
    chest: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=FemaleChestData)
    neck: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=LongLimbData)
    head: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=WideLimbData)
    
    # OTHER FIELDS OMITTED
    
    def draw(self, layout, context):
        box = layout.box()
        self.hips.draw(box, context)
        self.spine.draw(box, context)
        self.chest.draw(box, context)
        self.neck.draw(box, context)
        self.head.draw(box, context)

        # OTHER DRAW CALLS OMITTED


But FemaleSpineData (which extends LongLimbData) can call super().draw(layout, context) just fine. It shows the extra property that LongLimbData defines.
I've made sure the indents are 4 spaces at least 5 times now. I also tried installing another version of blender to no avail.

I see two possibilities.  One, the indentation for the LimbData and/or LongLimbData classes is not accurately shown in the question, and the draw() method is not actually a member of those classes.  Two, the code has another definition for the LongLimbData class that is overwriting the one shown here.

But FemaleSpineData (which extends LongLimbData) can do the draw calls just fine The FemaleSpineData class defines its own draw() method, so that's probably not meaningful.

The first line of the traceback is context.active_object.manifoldHuman.maleBody.draw(layout, context) but you are showing us the code for "FemaleBody...".

Sorry, maleBody is actually FemaleBodyData. I couldn't be bothered to refactor the code everywhere else when I was possibly going to remove that field.

Please update your question with the method in which self.neck is assigned to. (Yes, is there another definition of LongLimbData somewhere?

Turns out this was an issue with blender. Blender does not play nice when subclassing existing property groups and such. The correct way to use subclassing in this case is to use mix-in classes.
Example:
import bpy

class AbstractLimb:
    length: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Length", min=0.0)
    
    def Draw(self, layout, context):
        layout.prop(self, "length")

class LongLimb(AbstractLimb, bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    radius: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Radius", min=0.0)
    
    def Draw(self, layout, context):
        super().Draw(layout, context)
        layout.prop(self, "radius")

class WideLimb(AbstractLimb, bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    width: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Width", min=0.0)
    thickness: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Thickness", min=0.0)
    
    def Draw(self, layout, context):
        super().Draw(layout, context)
        layout.prop(self, "width")
        layout.prop(self, "thickness")

This threw no errors for me and was properly drawn by the UI.
